# How to pass two tables to a SQL Server function in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008. I have function in SQL like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNC_Maharat_RETURN_STUDENTID 
    (@TblMaharatId dbo.ListOfMaharatIDs READONLY,
     @TblSelectedStudents dbo.ListOfStudentsShomareMeli READONLY)
RETURNS @lstofmaharat TABLE(StudentId bigint)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE C1  CURSOR LOCAL SCROLL STATIC FOR 
         SELECT MaharatId 
         FROM @TblMaharatId

    DECLARE @TblResult table(StudentId bigint)
    DECLARE @MaharatId int

    OPEN C1

    FETCH FIRST FROM C1 INTO @MaharatId

    INSERT INTO @lstofmaharat
        SELECT a.ShomareMeli 
        FROM TblStudents A
        JOIN TblStudentMaharat B ON A.ShomareMeli = B.StudentId
        WHERE B.MaharatId = @MaharatId 
          AND a.ShomareMeli IN (SELECT StudentId FROM @TblSelectedStudents)

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @MaharatId

        INSERT INTO @TblResult
            SELECT StudentId 
            FROM @lstofmaharat
            INTERSECT
            SELECT a.ShomareMeli  
            FROM TblStudents A
            JOIN TblStudentMaharat B ON A.ShomareMeli = B.StudentId
            WHERE B.MaharatId = @MaharatId

     DECLARE @Count INT
     SELECT @Count=ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) FROM @TblResult
     IF @Count=0
     DELETE @lstofmaharat 





     ELSE
     DELETE @lstofmaharat 
     INSERT INTO @lstofmaharat 
     SELECT A.StudentId
     from
     @TblResult as a

     DECLARE @result XML = (SELECT * FROM @TblResult FOR XML AUTO)
     DECLARE @lstofma XML = (SELECT * FROM @lstofmaharat FOR XML AUTO)

     delete  from @TblResult
    END
    CLOSE C1
    DEALLOCATE C1
    RETURN 
END
```

I want to pass two tables to function like this:

```
      internal DataTable filter_tahsili_maharat(DataTable dtMaharatIds, DataTable dtStudentIds)
    {
        DataTable resTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", con))
            {
                //DataTable Sm = GetMaharatTable();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.FUNC_Maharat_RETURN_STUDENTID (@t,@y)", con);
                SqlParameter code1 = new SqlParameter("@t", SqlDbType.Structured);
                code1.Value = dtMaharatIds;
                code1.TypeName = "dbo.ListOfMaharatIDs";
               code1.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;

                SqlParameter code2 = new SqlParameter("@y", SqlDbType.Structured);
                code2.Value = dtStudentIds;
                code2.TypeName = "dbo.ListOfStudentsShomareMeli";
                code2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(code1);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(code2);
                da.Fill(resTable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("مشکلی در جستجو به وجود آمده است");
        }

        return resTable;
    }
```

but I get exception like this:

> Procedure or function dbo.FUNC_Maharat_RETURN_STUDENTID has too many arguments specified.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use parameters for table or column names like this: `INSERT INTO @lstofmaharat`. If you want to do this, you **must use** dynamic SQL

Comment: I tried it and it works in sql server.but it not works in c#

Comment: any body can help me??

Comment: Thank you for your answers !!!